# How can I customize the appearance of the tab control in Win32?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, tabcontrol

I need to use Win32 to manage a tab control. Managing tabs in Win32 is not very difficult, but I want to change the look of tabs, eg add an 'x' button on the tab to close it, change the color of the tab, etc. Can anyone tell me if there is any open source code available for this? What is the easiest and fastest way to get this done?

Comment: Can I change the shape of the tab?

Comment: Yes, if you owner-draw it, you can change the shape or customize it in any way. You've taken over control of how it's drawn.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to owner draw the tab control if you wish to customize its appearance.

You can find information about that here on MSDN: [About Tab Controls: Owner-Drawn Tabs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760550.aspx#owner_drawn_tabs)